# Is there a good order to put specific levels to make Bitizens go to residential levels?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

In TDS bitizens are not taking any interest in going to a residential level to stay; I currently have 25 bitizens and 27 floors, 9 of which are residential levels with 3 being un touched. Can anyone give me a a clue as to what I'm doing wrong or something that will entice bitizens more to want to rent out to stay and work for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Tiny Tower, I used to stack all my residential at the bottom and the shops at the top, so that if the bitizens requested low numbered floors I'd get new workers an if they requested high numbers I'd at least get the benefit of a large tip in exchange for missing out on a new resident.

I tried rearranging the floors in TDS to match the requested number, but the bitizens just changed the number so they'd go to the floor they'd originally asked for :(

Paying for residents isn't as good in TDS as it was in TT as getting a dream job nets you the same as you paid rather than double. 
So because of that I'd recommend trying to buy a recruiter VIP for less than 5 bux to get the best value. (Ie by keeping the lobby empty)

I have a speculative theory that a tower gains popularity by having a balanced mix of store types - this was definitely true of TT - I tried to get only the food stores and my game slowed right down - I've kept it balanced in TDS and have had no problems gaining bitizens.

Comment: Thank you, while I appreciate all replies this was the most helpful by giving me info based on TT and especially the bit on balanced mix of store types.

Answer (score 2):

Bitizens don't actually "choose" to stay in your tower, you can't actually make your tower "more enticing".

When a bitizen enters the elevator, he/she will ask to go to a specific level *at random*. If that floor is residential *and* it has a vacancy, then the bitizen will move in. (Otherwise you'll just get a tip (floor number x elevator multiplier), the bitizen will buy an item if the floor has any item in stock & take one minute off a timer if one is present on that floor).

To make bitizens move into you tower, you can either pay 1 imperial bux to fill a vacant spot or use a recruiting agent VIP when one is available.

Comment: I mean I understand this, I just read somewhere that how you stack your levels will make them come more. I know there isn't anyway to make a level more appealing but there has to be some reason that I hardly get any bitizens to want to move in.

Comment: @GkAllDayErryDay I agree.  It is random.  There is no way to influence where they will go.  If you aren't getting anyone to move in, the best bet is to wait for a VIP Recruiter.